# Wordpress - How to write to external database from HTML editor

Tags: wordpress

I made a wordpress plugin that displays information about chemicals stored in an external databse. I want to be able to edit this info using the wordpress editor. Is there a way to do this with filters or action hooks? Using the the_editor_content filter, I can load the data from the external database into the editors textarea but I need to make it submit it to the external database rather than the wordpress db.

EDIT: I found out theres a save_post action hook which calls a custom function every time a post is created or updated. I can use that to write to the external database, I just need to figure out how to stop wordpress from submitting the post to the wordpress db too.

Comment: The 'save_post' hook fires after the post has already been saved. You might want to look into ['wp_insert_post_data'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) to handle posts before they save, so that you can further manage the standard saving process.

Comment: The [`pre_post_update`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_post_update) looks like it might serve you better than `save_post` since it fires before commit to DB.

Comment: wp_insert_post_data worked, thanks.